# Best Practice for Designing User Roles and Permission System?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to add user roles and permission system into my web application built using PHP/MySQL. I want to have this functionality:

1. One root user can create sub-roots, groups, rules and normal users( all privileges) .
2. Sub-roots can create only rules, permissions and users for his/her own group ( no groups).
3. A user can access either content created by him or his group, based on the permission assigned to him, by group root.

I need the system to be flexible enough, so that new roles and permissions are assigned to content.

I have a `users` table storing group key along with other information. Currently I am using two feilds in each content table i.e. `createdBy` and `CreatedByGroup`, and using that as the point whether a certain user has permissions. But its not flexible enough, because for every new content, I have to go throug all data updates and permission updates. Please help me by discussing your best practices for schema design.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The pattern that suits your needs is called [role-based access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).

There are several good implementations in PHP, including [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html) (good documenation), [phpGACL](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/) and [TinyACL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tackle/). Most frameworks also have their own implementations of an ACL in some form.

Even if you choose to roll your own, it'll help you to review well factored solutions such as those.

Comment: Zend_Acl link is broken

Answer (score 46):

I Think bitwise operator are the best way to implement user permission.
Here I am showing how we can implement it with MySQL.

Below is a sample tables with some sample data:

**Table 1**: Permission table to store permission name along with it bit like 1, 2, 4, 8.. etc (multiple of 2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permission` (
  `bit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Insert some sample data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO `permission` (`bit`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'User-Add'),
(2, 'User-Edit'),
(4, 'User-Delete'),
(8, 'User-View'),
(16, 'Blog-Add'),
(32, 'Blog-Edit'),
(64, 'Blog-Delete'),
(128, 'Blog-View');
```

**Table 2**: User table to store user id,name and role. Role will be calculated as sum of permissions.
Example:

If user 'Ketan' having permission of 'User-Add' (bit=1) and 'Blog-Delete' (bit-64) so role will be 65 (1+64).
If user 'Mehata' having permission of 'Blog-View' (bit=128) and 'User-Delete' (bit-4) so role will be 132 (128+4).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data-

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `role`, `created_date`)
   VALUES (NULL, 'Ketan', '65', '2013-01-09 00:00:00'),
   (NULL, 'Mehata', '132', '2013-01-09 00:00:00');
```

Loding permission of user
After login if we want to load user permission then we can query below to get the permissions:

```
SELECT permission.bit,permission.name  
   FROM user LEFT JOIN permission ON user.role & permission.bit
 WHERE user.id = 1
```

Here user.role "&" permission.bit is a Bitwise operator which will give output as -

```
User-Add - 1
Blog-Delete - 64
```

If we want to check weather a particular user have user-edit permission or not-

```
  SELECT * FROM `user` 
     WHERE role & (select bit from permission where name='user-edit')
```

Output = No rows.

You can see also: http://sforsuresh.in/implemention-of-user-permission-with-php-mysql-bitwise-operators/

Comment: What is the maximum permissible value for the permission table? How many unique permissions can be inserted into permissions table? How about adding summation of all the possible permissions into user role column?

Comment: @traditional - the size would be to use a bigint, which is 64-bit, allowing for 64 permissions. If that's enough, this is a neat way of doing things. If that's not enough and you're not worried about space, having separate columns for each permission would probably be ok.

Comment: There is no concept of 'role' here -- what you have is a permission list per user.

Comment: True, no concept of role in this implementation, but this method allows you to do the most common function - check a user's permissions - very easily without too many abstraction layers.  It would be easy enough to implement a table with roles and a permission number that includes all the permissions allowed in that role (just as shown for a user above).  Then your UI allows the the user to be assigned one of more roles which sets that users permissions to the ORed sum of all the selected role's permission values. Now you have roles.

Comment: Sorry but what if you have a long list of permissions maybe like a hundred, how is this going to be feasible? Your data column is going to explode.

Comment: so far this is one good method am going to implement. i have a role_module table that lists all the modules in the system based on the role is modular you can just add new modules and assign who what role can access the module through this table. Probably you don't need to define permission for all modules you just need the basic 'view','add', 'update', 'delete', 'trash','restore' ==> then i relate them at the role_module with a numbering system like this solves my big problem of doing this to every user..... also user can have multiple roles through multiple contacts they have.

Comment: How would you query such a table though?

Answer (score 7):

I had a slightly different structure, but it should be able to serve as a reference.

Each user has a 'Role', 'GroupID' associate with it, and  Group table for which the GroupID refers to.
Then I have 3 permission table.

```
PermissionMaster(FormName)
```

`PermissionChild(PermissionMasterID, PermissionName, Desc, DefaultValue, DependOn)` and

```
PermissionGroupChild(GroupID, PermissionChildID, Allow)
```

PermissionMaster holds the name/form/module for which the permission refers to. PermissionChild will list all the possible permission available for each Master, such as 'Create', 'View', 'Edit', 'Delete', and description (I didn't have this on the first version, and it started to get confusing when there's too many permission setup even for 1 module). I allow adding more children to specifically refer to some function like 'ChangeTimeStamp', which would also allow more specific permission then 'Edit'

Then PermissionGroupChild is the link between PermissionChild and Group table. Every group will have a set of PermissionChild copied and set with default setting. Then I had a permission class which does the table query and check for each user. I only load it during login. Then in every form/module, I check for it's appropriate permission and applies the UI properly.

As for role, I only use it at the Login configuration page. Smaller Role value means higher ranked. So user can only see itself and those of Role value higher than itself. He/she can edit those of lower rank than itself but not similar.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you used PermissionChild - working on something and this seemed interesting. How was default value used. 
`PermissionChild(PermissionMasterID, PermissionName, Desc, DefaultValue, DependOn)`

Comment: For each form I have the basic permission for `Create`(Adding new entries), `View`(Without this the form is denied access), `Edit`(Editing existing entries) and `Delete`(delete an entry). I sometime have extra `PermissionChild` such as `ChangePassword`(change user's password in user management) etc. The default value a `Boolean` to indicate when  not override, whether is permission is allowed by default. Most common form would have `View`'s `DefaultValue=1`

Answer (score 7):

You might not want groups of permissions.  Instead create user groups, give user groups permissions, and put users in groups.  Users should also be able to override permissions from the groups they are in.  Deny should always override grant where a user is in more than one group with the pemission.

In summary:

- User has zero or more permissions (grany, deny)
- User is in zero or more groups
- Group has zero or more permissions (grant, deny)

Answer (score 2):

I have groups and users (like active directory LDAP solution). So if I give access to group I need that users in this group have herited accesses.

So, based on the @suresh-kamrushi answer below, I made this :

```
INSERT INTO `permission` (`bit`, `name`) VALUES
(1,   'add-yes'),
(2,   'add-no'),
(4,   'edit-yes'),
(8,   'edit-no'),
(16,  'del-yes'),
(32,  'del-no'),
(64,  'view-yes'),
(128, 'view-no');
```

If user have bit `00000000`, I take first two digits `00` that means `add-yes` and `add-no` are herited from group permissions.

If user have bit `01010110`, I take first two digits `01` that means `add-no` will prime on group permissions, so this user have no add permission. This bitwise says that user can only view.

It's also working with parent groups.

What do you think about this solution ?
Does anyone have got better way for that ?

Comment: Do not understand why 01 means user have no add permission. Can you explain more "that means add-no will prime on group permissions"?