# How to assign data only to users who have a specific role?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

If I have data which I only want to assign to users who have an admin role, how would I represent this in the db schema?  i.e. I have a users table, roles table, user_roles table and this particular user is linked to an admin role.  How would I then be able to specify information only for admin users?

Comment: attach a permissions field to the data?

Comment: Do you need to set the permissions on all the database, or is it per table permissions?

Comment: I'm not trying to set any permissions.  I'm just trying to be able to store attributes that relate only to admin users, like admin_power_level for instance.

Comment: I edited the post in that way. (Keeping archives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT4: So if I understand, you have the users table, role table and an association linking users to roles.

One idea would be to put the value in the role table, then basically you'll have multiple role for multiple admin levels.

Or you can create other fields in the association table, to parametrize the association, but that would impact all other association. (or ou can have : X is in group B with option1=1, option2=42, option3=NULL and treat options fields differently depending on the group)

Other idea, but I would have made it completely differently:

you treat groups as users, with a special field call isGroup [True/False]. Then you create the groupAssociation table which stores which user belongs to which group.

Example :

```
USER
--Id--    --IsGroup--
A         False
B         False
C         True
D         True

GROUPASSOCIATION
--uid--   --BelongsTo--
A          C
B          D
C          D
```

Note that you can cascade saying that C is included in D.
Then you create a privilege table and associate groups or user to certain privileges.

```
PRIVILEGE
--Id--    --Name--
1         Access Area 1
2         Access Area 2
3         Modify user
4         Edit on StackOverflow

PRIVILEGEASSOCIATION
--uid--   --pid--
A         4
C         2
D         1
C         3
```

So user A would have all privileges (one direct, two from C group, one for D group since C is included in D) and B would have only one (from group D)

Would it be better in your case?

---

EDIT3: Given your last comment, this in not valid anymore
The GRANT command will help you sort out your problem.

You can see it right there : [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

As an example :

```
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

You can do it for a column only, for all table, or all database as well

EDIT: Oh well, let me check for groups. I forgot that part.

EDIT2: I didn't see anything about group permission tuning in MySQL : [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,94280,94301#msg-94301) said it's not possible but it's quite old. But I came accros this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system) and they are using PHP to manage the groups.

Comment: Thx M'vy for taking the time out of your today to write such a detailed post!  I think my hypothetical example is way too confusing though.  As I commented in Simon's post, it's more like if I want to store home addresses, but only for users of the admin role, what table would this be stored on?

Comment: As you said, I would have put it into the user table, therefore making it null for non admin users. This because home address is a user property and it does not impedes the system to have null for others. BTW you can still check the coherence of your "ethic" by looking for non-admin users with home field not null.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is trying to set a field in the database where the user_role is equal to admin role. If this is the case then you would need to do something like:

```
UPDATE field FROM users LEFT JOIN user_role ON user.id = userrole.userid 
WHERE userrole.role = 'adminrole'
```

Now this would depend entirely on your schema, could you please post so we can give you a more accurate SQL command?

EDIT: ok reading the question again just confuses me. Please post your exact schema.

EDIT2:
With your example, it would make sense to store the extra field in the users table, since, an address is related to a user. You would only want to set this field if the users_role is equal to admin_user. This way you would also help if you needed to expand in the future. If not, you could also define another table called admin_addresses. This would only be specified for admin users and could look like: Admin_address_table (userID,address).

To enforce this logic (either way) you could use e.g. a stored procedure. Pass the data to a stored procedure and it would update the address field if the user_role was equal to admin_user. Alternmatively you could use application logic when updating your data.

It is really up to you which way to go. You have a better idea of what *may* happen in the future and what exact information needs to be stored. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Simon, thx for taking the time to post an answer.  Sorry for making my question so confusing.  What I'm trying to do, for example, is store home addresses, but only for users who are admins.  My problem is that I don't know what table I would put this home address field in (for simplicity, let's just say its one field for the whole address).  Would it be in the users table or even the roles table, and therefore NULL for all non admins, as in some kind of single inheritance table?  or Would it be in a separate admin info table, along with any other admin specific information.