# User rights stored in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am developing a Webapp with user rights. The user rights should be stored in the database and I am now puzzeling with the how to.

I thought about the possibility to use flags like in an "ordinary" application.

```
0 - NoRights 
1 - User
2 - Support 
4 - Finance 
8 - Admin
```

The actual right would then consist of one or more added numbers.
A *User* with *Support* rights would then have the userright *3*.

**What is best practice in Database moddeling to store userrights?**

I am using a  Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 but I guess this question has a database agnostic answer

**EDIT:**

Here some resources I found on my way and with the kind help of the people who answered and commented.

[Best Practice for Designing User Roles and Permission System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system)

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63518/mac-vs-dac-vs-rbac

Comment: Check if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl Yes this covers it pretty much. I wonder why I havent found this question :/ , definetly many thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Bongo, glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Not really related to your SQL question, but since you're using SQL Server are you creating a .NET web app? If so have you looked into ASP.net identity which will potentially do most of your identity management for you instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @JamiePollard That wasn't really the issue but I will look into it and then make a decision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is many to many relation. Meaning that one user can have multiple roles and one role can be attached to multiple users.

Ie user1 can have roles 1 and 4 and role 1 can be hold by user1 and user2.

This normally is modelled using bridge tables,  ie "

User(userId, name)
Role(roleId, description)

UserRole(userId, roleId)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Hope this helps

Comment: I would have thought that I could implement it like that but I wanted to be 100% sure thanks :)

Comment: Not to worry, glad I was able to help.