# Database design: multiple users with different roles, extra field or separate table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm modelling a database schema that has the requirement of including multi-user account functionality:

> A multiple user account enables multiple users to login to the same
>   account in order to do the job according to their permission level.
>   This means that it is possible to maintain a single account for your
>   entire marketing team. The account owner can add as many users as
>   he/she wants and limit what permissions each of them has. You can
>   choose a role for each user: account manager, marketing executive,
>   marketing assistant, etc… or create a customized permission.

At the moment I have one users table that stores the information of a generic user with the username and password etc. How would one implement a multi-user account functionality? Could an extra field be added to the users table that simply indicates the role? Would a separate table be required? I would like to use the principle of keeping this simple where possible but don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Each user is a assigned to one group, is that correct? In that case, the `user` table can have a `groupid` which is a foreign key to a `user_group` table which lists all the access roles that you have.

Now the `group` (groupid) may have a number of "access rights" of what they can (or cannot) do on the system, which can be defined by you. You can refer to this as a default set of access rights.

If you want to create a customized permission, it's best to read this SO question / the first two answers in the least:

[Best Practice for Designing User Roles and Permission System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system)

In the second example which discusses bitwise operators (if you are doing this custom, without help of a framework as discussed in the first answer), this is interesting assuming you understand the concept. Effectively you are summing up the decimal integers but they are being compared in binary to know what roles are granted for a given user. You can use this concept to also define what access rights each preset `groupid` has for predefined roles.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle we have "[Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm#DBSEG007)". For SQL Server / Azure we have "[Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security)". Whichever RDBMS you are using, check for similar feature. It is most efficient for this scenario.